# Reverse engineering in c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, reverse-engineering

I need to extract the list of dependencies out of a compiled dll. The dll is written in either c# or vb.net, and this process should be done recursively, i.e. a dependency might have a dependency of its own and so on..

Telerik's "JustDecompile" works perfectly, but I want to write code that does that, so I can have a tree of dependencies at my disposal.

Any ideas?

Comment: you can try to `Load` the `Assembly` using `Reflection`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need anything special, you can use the built-in `System.Reflection` classes:

```
public static void DisplayReferences() {

     Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load( ... );
     HashSet<String> seen = new HashSet<String>();
     DisplayReferences( 0, seen, assembly.GetName() );
}

private static void DisplayReferences(Int32 indent, HashSet<String> seen, AssemblyName name) {

    Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load( name )
    foreach(AssemblyName childName in assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies() ) {

        if( !seen.Contains( childName.FullName ) ) {

            seen.Add( childName.FullName );
            Console.WriteLine( "{0}{1}", "".PadLeft( indent ), childName.FullName );
            DisplayReferences( indent + 1, childName );
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This answer does not handle the rare but possible case where there are circular references amongst the transitive closure of assemblies. The other answer handles this situation correctly.

Comment: @EricLippert I didn't know circular references were possible, I thought the runtime or JIT compiler would complain and abort.

Comment: I encourage you to read this article by my former compiler team colleague on this subject. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2013/11/23/circular-assembly-references-in-the-net-framework.aspx

Comment: @EricLippert I've amended my answer to keep track of seen assemblies. It feels like a hack to use `FullName`, but `AssemblyName` doesn't override GetHashCode and GetEquals.

Answer (score 1):

My version of code (shows all dependencies of dependent assemblies):

```
public IEnumerable<Assembly> GetAssemblyDependencies(Assembly assembly)
{
    HashSet<string> hash = new HashSet<string>();

    Func<AssemblyName, Assembly> loader = (name) =>
    {
        try
        {
            return Assembly.Load(name.FullName);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    };

    List<Assembly> queue = new List<Assembly>() { assembly };
    List<Assembly> newQueue = new List<Assembly>();
    while (queue.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (var asm in queue.SelectMany(e => from x in e.GetReferencedAssemblies()
                                                  let loadedAssembly = loader(x)
                                                  where loadedAssembly != null
                                                  select loadedAssembly))
        {
            string fullName = asm.FullName;
            if (!hash.Contains(fullName))
            {
                // new assembly
                hash.Add(fullName);
                yield return asm;
                newQueue.Add(asm);
            }
        }

        var temp = queue;
        queue = newQueue;
        newQueue = temp;
        newQueue.Clear();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
foreach (var assembly in from e in 
GetAssemblyDependencies(this.GetType().Assembly)
                         orderby e.FullName
                         select e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(assembly.FullName);
}
```

Result (for my test console):

```
Accessibility, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Genesis, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Genesis.Plugins, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Genesis.Social.Owin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Microsoft.JScript, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Microsoft.Owin, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
Microsoft.Owin.Security, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
Microsoft.Transactions.Bridge, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.Compiler, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler, Version=2.2.2.26204, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0d013ddd5178a2ae
mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
OpenPortal, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
Owin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f0ebd12fd5e55cc5
ServiceCore, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
SMDiagnostics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Activities.DurableInstancing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Configuration.Install, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Data.OracleClient, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Data.Services.Client, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Data.Services.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Data.SqlXml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Deployment, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.DirectoryServices.Protocols, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Drawing.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Dynamic, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.IdentityModel.Selectors, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Messaging, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Net.Http.WebRequest, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Numerics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Runtime.Caching, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Runtime.DurableInstancing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Runtime.Remoting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.ServiceModel.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.ServiceModel.Internals, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.ServiceProcess, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.Optimization, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.RegularExpressions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Xaml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Xaml.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
T4MVCExtensions, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7b26dc2a43f6a0d4
WebCore, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
WebCore.Users, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```